# Azure Service Connection: escape character in login

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to access a host from Azure Pipeline using scp/ssh pipeline task with SSH service connection. The login contains a backslash; when I configure Service Connection with a login=my\login, the backslash messes up the ssh command. When I try to escape it with quotation marks or double, the server receives extra back slashes (login="my\login" -> `my\\login`; login=`my\\login` -> `my\\\\login`; login="my\login" -> my\\login). What is a correct way to create a service connection with just one backslash in login?

Answer (score 0):

> What is a correct way to create a service connection with just one backslash in login?

You could try to use the 2 backslahes `\\` in the service connection, one backslash escaping the second:

```
my\\login
```

Please check this thread for some more details: [special characters in username while creating ssh connection](https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2/issues/270)

Comment: Yeah I tried it, it became my\\\\login in server authentication logs - looks like azure tries to escape '\' symbol on its own... but not when there's just one of those

Comment: @TatianaDidik, I see. But I could not get the authentication info in the build log. So, I want to confirm that you are use `my\login` for the Username in the azure devops service connection? And how to check the `my\\\\login` in server authentication logs? Some image will be better. Thanks.